# AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcgis-10.5, assertionerror

I am trying to publish a draft service definition using arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft and am getting the referenced Assertion Error. I've tried the responses to users with similar questions with no luck.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env

# Set local variables
wrkspc = r"\\intruder11\grc\sw\core\dev\gp\hosted_services_sp"
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + 'NoMap.mxd')
outputFolder = r"\\intruder11\grc\sw\core\dev\gp\hosted_services_sp"
sddraft = mapDoc + service + '.sddraft'
summary = 'Test of publishing automation'
tags = 'CNR Southwest, dev, test, acc'

# Sign-in to Portal for ArcGIS
logger.info('Signing into built-in ACC account')
arcpy.SignInToPortal_server("--","--", "https://--")
    

### create service definition draft
analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES',con, True, None, summary, tags)

### Sign out from ArcGIS Online
arcpy.SignOutFromPortal_server()
```

Comment: Your mapDoc variable has no backslash between your workspace and MXD names.

Comment: @PolyGeo can you help me with the syntax? Struggling to determine the placement of the backslash. Thanks

Comment: `os.path.join(wrkspc, 'NoMap.mxd')`

Answer (score 1):

Your mapDoc variable has no backslash between your workspace and MXD names. One way to address that is by using Python string formatting.

I would replace this:

```
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + 'NoMap.mxd')
```

with this:

```
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'{0}\{1}'.format(wrkspc,'NoMap.mxd'))
```

Comment: Why not `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(wrkspc, 'NoMap.mxd'))`?  I feel it's always better to let the system create the filepath rather than construct it myself, so just wondering

Comment: @Midavalo it’s a personal preference. I don’t like importing an additional library when something’s so easy to do without.

Comment: that makes sense.  I guess I'm just in the (possibly bad) habit of always adding `import os` :)

Comment: @Midavalo The way I do it probably stems from teaching so many non-programmers to code with ArcPy and Python. Python string formatting is so useful for constructing messages, SQL expressions paths, etc that I think it’s worth mastering it’s syntax early.